# Why can't I login to my Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, .htaccess, permissions

I recently updated Wordpress and I am now locked out of my dashboard. The theme is working so the site is visible, but it would seem none of the forms are being executed, including the login form. I don't see any errors on the form, the page just refreshes.

http://smallbusinessadvisory.com/wp-login.php

Normally you'd see an error if one of the fields was blank when you hit submit. The same goes for the Gravity Form on the site:

http://smallbusinessadvisory.com/request-consultation/

The page displays but the form doesn't show any errors like it should. It's like it's not being executed.

I asked the hosting company about it, because I thought it might had something to do with permissions, but I've checked, and I can see permissions are 644 on all files and 755 on directories.

At first, I was getting a 403 when I tried visiting `wp-login.php` so I added this to my `.htaccess`:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

This allowed me to display the page, but again, the login form isn't executing and the page just refreshes.

Outside of that my `.htaccess` only contains the basic WP configuration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What am I missing? Why aren't these forms being executed?

Comment: why do you add `<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>` to .htaccess, you can remove it all.

Comment: If I remove that from the `.htaccess`, `wp-login.php` serves a 403.

Comment: try open the wp-config.php and compare with wp-config-smaple.php see anything need to pay attention. eg if you're using any cache plugin.

Comment: I installed a new version of 4.1 and WP created the wp-config.php file on the fly using a UI, and I haven't edited it.

Comment: have you seen this? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-loginphp-403-error

Answer (score 0):

Usually white pages in WordPress are attributed to fatal PHP errors. I recommend enabling the WP_DEBUG settings inside of WordPress's wp-config.php in the root directory.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This will cause PHP errors, warnings and notices to **display across the entire site.** If this is a live site and displaying errors is not an option use the following settings to log the errors but not display them.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```